# python pandas multi index how to move rows down?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Hey I am trying to make a dataframe ready for exportation into latex and I can't figure out how to change the order of my dataframe manually, i can sort it etc, but i can't get it to show the specific order i require:

```
    Hyper-parameter                  H-parameter values                             
CNN activation function          relu                         0.018254  0.018359
                                 tanh                         0.018249  0.018348
CNN filter layers                16                                NaN  0.018353
                                 32                                NaN  0.018338
                                 64                                NaN  0.018368
Feature collections              daytime                      0.017845  0.017947
                                 daytime + sensors            0.020593  0.020344
                                 daytime + wind + irradiance  0.017080  0.017311
                                 daytime + wind + sensors     0.019660  0.019819
                                 irradiance                   0.017133  0.017413
                                 pressure and humidity        0.017735  0.017828
                                 rain                         0.017983  0.017953
                                 sensors                      0.020103  0.020075
                                 temperature                  0.018081  0.017964
                                 univariate                   0.017827  0.017747
                                 wind                         0.017216  0.017571
                                 wind + irradiance            0.016605  0.017027
                                 wind + sensors               0.019407  0.019594
LSTM activation function         relu                         0.018299       NaN
                                 tanh                         0.018204       NaN
LSTM history vector length       60                           0.018246       NaN
                                 80                           0.018253       NaN
                                 100                          0.018255       NaN
Learning rate                    0.0001                       0.018424  0.018496
                                 0.0005                       0.018156  0.018259
                                 0.001                        0.018174  0.018305
MaxPooling layer size            3                            0.018212  0.018300
                                 5                            0.018230  0.018378
                                 7                            0.018313  0.018381
Second CNN kernel                False                             NaN  0.018407
                                 True                              NaN  0.018300
Second set of cnn+pooling layers False                             NaN  0.018333
                                 True                              NaN  0.018374
```

This is my dataframe, I would really like to have control over the order of the Hyper parameters. For example I would like to move `CNN activation function` and `CNN filter layers` down below `Feature collections`. Any idea on how to accomplish this would be great.

for reference, here is a toy example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}, index=['A', 'b', 'C', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
arrays = [[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], ['red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue', 'red', 'blue']]
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('number', 'color')
df

              a
number color   
1      red    1
       blue   2
2      red    3
       blue   4
3      red    5
       blue   6
```

How to move the contents of "number' 2 to the top?

Answer (score 3):

Nevermind, After more than an hour of searching i made this post, and 10 minutes later i found the answer. using the example at the bottom of my question:

```
df.reindex([2,1,3], level=0)
df

              a
number color   
2      red    3
       blue   4
1      red    1
       blue   2
3      red    5
       blue   6
```